# jquery - get height of previous multiple div

Tags: jquery

How can i get height of multiple divs like this one:

```
<div class="alert"></div>
<div class="alert"></div>
<div class="alert"></div>
```

then add it to the `top` property of each div.
This is their height :

```
.alert {height:15px;}
```

so after load it will be :

```
<div class="alert"></div>
<div class="alert" style="top:15px"></div>
<div class="alert" style="top:30px"></div>
```

I can only manage to get the height of previous div and not the other previous div:

```
 $('.alert').each(function () {
       var posTop = $(this).prev('.alert').innerHeight();
       $(this).css({ top: posTop + 'px' });
   });
```

pls. help thanks!

Comment: what are you trying to achieve is unclear...

Comment: i stated it earlier at "so after load it will be"...

Comment: wrap every `alert` div i a parent `div#msg` or something to make your life easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a variable to store the cumulative top value

```
var top = 0;
$('.alert').each(function () {
    var posTop = $(this).prev('.alert').innerHeight();
    if (top) {
        $(this).css({
            top: top + 'px'
        });
    }
    top += $(this).innerHeight();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Lb54ocq0/)

Answer (score 1):

If the heights are the same across all divs you could try this:

```
$('.alert').each(function (index) {
   var posTop = $(this).prev('.alert').innerHeight()*index;
   $(this).css({ top: posTop + 'px' });
});
```

If they're not and you truly need a cumulative height calculation you might try something like this:

```
$('.alert').each(function () {
   var heightAbove = 0;
   var posTop = $(this).prevAll('.alert').each(function(){
       heightAbove += $(this).innerHeight();
   });
   $(this).css({ top: heightAbove+ 'px' });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [prevAll()](http://api.jquery.com/prevall/) to select all previous alert.

like this: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ua82xL8q/3/)

```
  $('.alert').each(function () {
       var top = 0;
       $(this).prevAll('.alert').each(function(c) {
           top += $(this).innerHeight();
       })
       $(this).css({ top: top + 'px' });
   });
```